# Path Animation with curve Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have a UIView that I want to animate on a curved path similar to a download flying to the dock in Safari. I'm not sure how to do it as I'm sure it involves Core Graphics and Core Animation. The last answer I found was from 2011 and uses functions deprecated in iOS 6 and fails to run as is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation) which has a path property that it will animate along.

There is also an example here its for mac and its in objective C.  if you can't figure it out I can post a Swift 3 example later:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html

Comment: I know Objective-C too, so I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Let's take curve points p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5, & find mid point for each pair of adjacent points. Label m1 as the mid point for p1 and p2. Similarly for m2, m3, m4.

- Add quad curve to point m2 with p2 as a control point.
- Add quad curve to point m3 with p3 as a control point.
- Add quad curve to point m4 with p4 as a control point.

Code:

```
CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;

UIView *aniView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, screenHeight, 50, 50)];
[aniView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
aniView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
[self.view addSubview:aniView];


UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[movePath moveToPoint:aniView.center];
[movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth-50,screenHeight-50)
                 controlPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth/2,screenHeight-150)];
CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
moveAnim.path = movePath.CGPath;
moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim,  nil];
animGroup.duration = 2.0;

[CATransaction begin]; {
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [aniView.layer removeAllAnimations];
        [aniView removeFromSuperview];
    }];

    [aniView.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];

} [CATransaction commit];
```

Copy past above code into some method and try calling the method...